How to receive packets on an interface without an IP address and route them to the local routing table?
I have a scenario where I use OpenELB as a load banalcer to announce my interface's MAC address and External IP address(192.168.41.71) on my Kubernetes cluster.
As I understand it, I don't need the interface's ip address, because the outside world only needs to know the EIP address and the Mac address of the interface.
My question is: how can I receive packets without the interface IP address and forward them to the local routing table by IPVS?
When I set an ip address randomly, the packets can be received and forwarded normally. However If I delete the interface's IP address then it doesn't work.


I don't need the interface's ip address

Depending on exactly what is in place on that host, that's no likely to work.
Running without an IP address on an interface requires a) the host to still accept IP packets (IP can't be unbound, binding usually requires an address), and b) all other nodes on the same L2 segment to already know that 'gateway's' MAC address (since ARP/NDP won't work).
If you can't meet both requirements, just add an address to that interface. After all, private IP addresses or even link local come for free.

Thanks for your explanation! It seems I still need to add an IP address on the interface.
